# Updating DOM images array with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web

My html contains different images, without any legality - all located under some table. for example `homepage.htm`:

```
<table id="imagesTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="img1.png">
            <div>
                <img src="img2.png">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <img src="img3.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The images sources in this page can be different every time I'm getting the page (but all other elements structure stays as is) and I want to update the page every 5 sec and update the new images instead of the old one (without refreshing the page). I tried to implement it with the following approach (without a succeed):

```
function updatePage()
{
    $("#imagesTable").load("homepage.htm #imagesTable");
    window.setTimeout("updatePage()",5000);
}
...
<body onload="updatePage();">
....
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong? any other suggestions how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Use `setTimeout(updatePage,5000);` instead. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Could it be a browser caching problem?  It would make a big difference if you told us what the problem actually is?

Comment: Currently the existing images elements do change - but the new one don't (new images can be added into the table..)

Comment: + it's doesn't work on IE7 (I'm using jQuery 1.8.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across my question again, so I'll add a short answer - my solution to the problem:

These images purpose was to indicate some of the system status; thus, I decided to separate the view and the data (MVC) and I've added JSON with the statuses state, which is called every 5 seconds (via ajax). Now in the client I've recreated the relevant DOM sections with the new images - which are suitable to the new system status.

Hope that's will help someone in the future :-)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
$("#imagesTable").load("homepage.htm #imagesTable");
window.setTimeout("updatePage()",5000);
```

With:

```
$("#imagesTable").load("homepage.htm #imagesTable *");
window.setTimeout(updatePage,5000);
```

Comment: Doesn't help :( what does the asterisk stands for?

Comment: @ItayB: * stands for all types of children. It means we get only the children of `#imagesTable`